# Create Wordpress shortcode with php code inside

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I'm working with visual composer and custom fields. i have the code for insert direct in PHP, but i can't create shortcode for this.

```
<div id="search-nacionalidad"><p class="<?php the_field('nacionalidad'); ?> noselect" title="<?php the_field('nacionalidad'); ?>" alt="<?php the_field('nacionalidad'); ?>"><?php the_field('nacionalidad'); ?></p></div>
```

How can I write a shortcode for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you create a shortcode? What have you tried? What was the problem?

Comment: @Milo Hi and thanks for ask. The problem is i'm creating a grid template. I have a custom field with all countries, and i want show flag, not text. I want change for example, SPAIN with flag image. The code works, but i need insert in visual composer, and only i can do it with shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a shortcode is fairly simple, it only needs a shortcode name and maybe  some arguments. Here is a simple one for you:

```
add_shortcode('my-shortcode','my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function(){ 
    return '<div id="search-nacionalidad"><p class="'. get_field('nacionalidad').' noselect" title="'.get_field('nacionalidad').'" alt="'. get_field('nacionalidad').'">'.get_field('nacionalidad').'</p></div>';
}
```

Now, using `[my-shortcode]` exactly does what your code does. However I'm not sure how do you use this, whether in a loop or not. If you need to pass the post's ID too, you need to use attributes. Take a look at this:

```
add_shortcode('my-shortcode','my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function($atts){ 
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '0',
    ), $atts, 'my-shortcode' );
    $id = $atts['id'];
    return '<div id="search-nacionalidad"><p class="'. get_the_field('nacionalidad',$id).' noselect" title="'.get_the_field('nacionalidad',$id).'" alt="'. get_the_field('nacionalidad',$id).'">'.get_the_field('nacionalidad',$id).'</p></div>';
}
```

Now if you use `[my-shortcode id="123"]` it will execute the code for the post that has an ID of 123. If no ID is provided, a default ID of 0 will be used instead.